# C# .net windows service to communicate with remote web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, filesystemwatcher

I have a requirement which i'm not is actually achieveable in C# / .net.

This is what i have to do:

- Write a C# windows service which runs constantly and monitors a folder
- Upon changes it initates and parses files in that folder
- Take this file and pass it to the remote web service (soap encapsulation).

It seems pretty simple but if its not possible to do this I'm open to other easier or better solutions.

---

one thing i would add is file is actually sitting on FTP folder not a regular folder.

Comment: Not a great question: Its all perfectly possible, and you seem to have broadly the right ideas. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: i have two specific problem

1) file needs to be readed over FTP or shared folder over network
2) webservice of file content is over SOAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is possible

1. [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) lets you monitor file system changes
2. A example of [WCF upload](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Upload-files-using-a-REST-13f16af2) file sample

Comment: Have the occasional race conditions in FileSystemWatcher been resolved? I know there were some occasional oddities in whether a new file was detected...

Comment: To help with all the issues of the FileSystemWatcher, we overlaid polling on top of that when writing Topshelf: https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/tree/master/src/Topshelf/FileSystem

Comment: @parapura rajkumar the WCF upload link you gave it points to REST service do you have SOAP link?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly as easy as it sounds. Create a windows service, reference your SOAP API through "Add Web References", and use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to monitor file changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could you `FileSystemWatcher` like some of the others have suggested, but I personally wouldn't because it's unreliable.

I would use the `File.Exists` method combined with a `Timer` and poll at intervals, much more reliable